# Alt + Z shortcut conflicts with Geforce Experience overlay

Tags: shortcut

How do I make it so when I press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> it actually works because when I do it, it doesn't work and instead, the Geforce Experience overlay pops up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the Nvidia control panel and disable the overlay.

Steps from  [a web search](https://www.partitionwizard.com/amp/partitionmagic/how-to-disable-nvidia-overlay.html)

- Right click on the Nvidia system tray icon and select NVIDIA GeForce Experience.
- Log into your NVIDIA account.
- Click the Settings icon (gear) on top right.
- In the GENERAL tab, turn off IN-GAME OVERLAY and exit.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the panel for clarity.

Comment: The problem is I only want to disable it for Blender.

Comment: This is an old question, but for posterity: https://www.reddit.com/r/GeForceExperience/comments/khegza/how_to_tell_geforceexperience_that_zoom_is_not_a/ggr3k6n/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the overlay enabled, it's a better option to change the keybinding itself. I know this isn't as good as disabling it only for a certain program, but at least you can set and forget.

- Open the overlay panel with Alt+Z
- Click the gear settings icon
- Click on Keyboard Shortcuts
- Change your shortcut to a different binding so it doesn't conflict with Blender (I used Alt+X)